# Using one ButtonStyle for more than one Button[Libgdx Scene2d]

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm making an interface using Libgdx Scene2d, and I have more than one button which all require different style, this means I have to create one buttonStyle for each button?

```
        btnStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        btnStyle.up = btnSkin.getDrawable("boxBtn");
        btnStyle.checked = btnSkin.getDrawable("boxBtn1");

        btnBox = new Button(btnStyle);

        anotherButton = new Button(newStyle?) //this is what I mean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. For each button that requires a different style, you will need a different `TextButtonStyle`.

```
TextButtonStyle styleOne = new TextButtonStyle();
styleOne.up = ...someDrawable1

TextButtonStyle styleTwo = new TextButtonStyle();
styleTwo.up = ...someDrawable2

TextButton button1 = new TextButton("Button1", styleOne);
TextButton button2 = new TextButton("Button2", styleTwo);
```

If you find that you are using the same set of styles over and over again, you could create `static` styles and use those for your buttons.

```
public class Styles {
    public static final TextButtonStyle styleOne = new TextButtonStyle();
    public static final TextButtonStyle styleTwo = new TextButtonStyle();

    public static void initStyles() {
         styleOne.up = ...

         styleTwo.up = ....
    }
}
```

Then call `Styles.initStyles()` when you've loaded your assets.

If you want to customize each style, but still use a set of default style attributes, you could try something like this:

```
public class Styles {

    public static TextButtonStyle createTextButtonStyle(Drawable up, Drawable down) {
        TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
        style.up = up;
        style.down = down;
        style.font = Assets.getDefaultFont() //For example
        style.fontColor = Assets.getDefaultFontColor() //For example
    }
}
```

Then when you want to create a button, you can just do:

```
TextButton button = new TextButton("Text", Styles.createTextButtonStyle(drawable1, drawable2));
```

Hope this helps clear some things up.